# Can I do a "lazy" promise with Bluebird.js?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I want a construct similar to promise that waits until [`then`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler---function-progresshandler----promise) is called before it runs. That is, if I never actually call `then`, the promise will never run.

Is this possible?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why not just have a function that executes when you call it? Also - nobody owes any explanation for downvotes, the explanation is implicit: Somebody thinks your question isn't useful, lacks research or is unclear.

Comment: Because the resulting promise might have `then` called on it multiple times (before or after it's actually resolved, that's why I need it to be a promise not a function). Or it might not get called at all, in which case I don't want to waste time executing it.

Comment: That's a different pattern, external to promises. Just make a function which returns a promise, but which memoizes that promise.

Comment: "That's a different pattern, external to promises." Fair enough, I just thought there might be such thing as a "lazy promise" because it seems like it might be a common use case. Sorry for asking.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry for asking, I personally see nothing wrong with the question, and I'm not sure why it's attracting downvotes, except that it indicates a bit of a misunderstanding in how promises work. I will amend my answer.

Comment: This is a legitimate question about concurrency with promises though.

Comment: For an example implementation where this concept is applied see the [Knex](http://knexjs.org/#Promises-then) query builder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make a function which creates and returns a promise on first invocation, but returns the same promise on each subsequent invocation:

```
function getResults() {
  if (getResults.results) return getResults.results;

  getResults.results = $.ajax(...); # or where ever your promise is being built

  return getResults.results;
}
```

Promises don't work in such a way that they could support lazy loading. Promises are created by asynchronous code in order to communicate a result. Until the async code has been invoked, there simply *is no promise*.

You could certainly write a promise-like object which did lazy invocation, but code that generated these promises would be very different:

```
// Accepts the promise-returning function as an argument
LazyPromise = function (fn) {
  this.promise = null;
  this.fn = fn
}

LazyPromise.prototype.then = function () {
  this.promise = this.promise || fn();
  this.promise.then.apply(this.promise, arguments)
}

// Instead of this...
var promise = fn();

// You'd use this:
var promise = new LazyPromise(fn);
```

It's better in this uncommon use to make the actual *creation* of the promise lazy (as in either above example), rather than trying to make promises themselves responsible for lazy-evaluation.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a concept of lazy promises, see the [Lazy promises (making `done` compulsory)](https://github.com/promises-aplus/unhandled-rejections-spec/issues/8) and [Alternative interfaces and Lazy promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/98) discussions. They are however not yet supported in any of the mainstream libraries like bluebird

Comment: Interesting similar concept by caolan https://github.com/caolan/highland . Also +1 for that last line.

Comment: @Bergi That requires the use of a constructor which is pretty much never useful - it is almost always used as an anti-pattern when promise chaining is not understood (not using the promise they already have).