# In Q promises, why is fcall called immediatelly?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Having this code

```
var Q = require('q');

var first = Q.fcall(function() {
    console.log('This will be output before actual resolution?');
    return "This is the result.";
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Gonna resolve.');
    first.then(function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Why the result is

```
This will be output before actual resolution?
Gonna resolve.
This is the result.
```

Instead of

```
Gonna resolve.
This will be output before actual resolution?
This is the result.
```

And how do I make the function be called only after `then` was called?

Comment: how will it know to call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how (typical Javascript) promises work. They don't wait around until you call `.then` on them. They do their work, and when it's done, they call any functions that were passed into `.then`.

So to your question "how do I make the function be called only after then was called?", you can't, at least not the way you're trying to do. That's not how promises work.

But you can of course do this:

```
var Q = require('q');

var getFirst = function () {
    return Q.fcall(function() {
        console.log('This will be output before actual resolution?');
        return "This is the result.";
    });
};

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Gonna resolve.');
    getFirst().then(function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: +1, but notice that there are indeed ideas for "lazy promises" that would do computations only when `.then()` was called on them. Those would of course be only used without side effects like `console.log` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out. I learned recently that F#'s async functions work something like that, and .NET's `Task`s do as well. Are there any well-known Javascript libraries that have the lazy promises you describe?

Comment: @Bergi lazy promises could be costly for memory.

Comment: @JLRishe: Well-known? Not so really :-) My own pet library is built on lazy primitives (which means a whole chain is lazy), and I've heard of some others. A trivial constructor implementation is [then/lazy-promise](https://github.com/then/lazy-promise), and see also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21957187/1048572).

Comment: @DanielA.White: [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) can be costly, but it can also reduce memory footprint. It can be slower, but it can also improve performance. It always depends on how you use it :-)