# Promise.all and to be executed only during the all (==lazily)

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to better understand how to run Promise.all that will execute the relevant methods only during the "all"

In this specific flow, the methods are being executed immediately.
what am i missing?

```js
var p1 = p.connectToServer(platform1, username1, password1)
var p2 = p.connectToServer(platform2, username2, password2)
var p3 = p.connectToServer(platform3, username3, password3)

//some logic to decide what to show and what to filter out
//it might not make sense in this snippet, but in the full code-base 
//this seperation is important
var params = [p3,p2]

Promise.all(params)
.then((responses) => {
    console.log("--- value ---")
    console.log(responses.length)
}
```

P.S. In my case, there is one place preparing the functions for a later stage, and some other logic happening in parallel, that helps to understand what methods shouldn't run and should be filtered out (before the execution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957187/can-i-do-a-lazy-promise-with-bluebird-js

Comment: "kind of lazily"? That requirement makes no sense. `Promise.all()` receives an array of promises and notifies you when they all have resolved, and that's it. The word "lazy" does not even fit here. How do you define it, exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak - kind of lazily means "start resolving promises after you push them inside Promise.all" which you need sometimes.

Comment: That's still a poorly defined requirement. *When* do you need that, and what for? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @libik There is no such thing as "start resolving". You either call `resolve` or you don't, and when you do that's the point in time where the promise resolves.

Comment: See below the chosen answer and how i solved my own case.
let me know how to edit the question so it will make sense and will be valuable for others instead of just voting down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link in comment by Antonio Narkevich is reasonable, but from my point of view it is kind of overengineered solution.

The answer is basically "no". No, you cannot control the flow of Promise resolving. Once the Promise is created, you have no control over "when and how" it is being resolved.

The Promise.all is just waiting after all the Promises are resolved and then it returns their values.

If you need something to create promise more dynamically, the easiest way is to make some kind of factory method.

```
const giveMePromise = () => Promise.resolve(10);
// some code ...
giveMePromise().then()
```

If you can use async/await, it can be used very easily (you can also put all promises inside array and then await the Promise.all) :

```
async () => {
  var p1 = () => p.connectToServer(platform1, username1, password1)
  var p2 = () => p.connectToServer(platform2, username2, password2)
  var p3 = () => p.connectToServer(platform3, username3, password3)

  const responses = [];
  var params = [p1,p2,p3]
  for (let i=0; i < params.length; i++){
    const response = await params[i]();
    responses.push(responses);
  }

  console.log("--- value ---")
  console.log(responses.length)
}
```

On the other hand, be very careful with "functions inside functions" when using async/await as it is not working as you would probably expect. In this case - using `params.forEach()` would not work.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. i did something similar with this two lines

var p1 = () => p.createBroadcast(platform1, username1, password1)
var p2 = () => p.createBroadcast(platform2, username2, password2)
var p3 = () => p.createBroadcast(platform3, username3, password3)

//some logic that decides that we need only this
//it might not make sense in this example, but it is much more readable
//and reasonable in my context + decide the order to start executing
var paramsToExecute = [p3, p2]

Promise.all(paramsToExecute.map( action => action())
.then(...)